# I would like to manipulate captured data from a regular expression return

Tags: html, regex, dreamweaver

I am writing a command that will search my html document and add an id to any heading tag based on the text node. I wanted to know if it is possible to capture the text node and then replace white space with hyphens.

e.g.

```
<h2>This is a heading</h2>
```

would become

```
<h2 id="this-is-a-heading">This is a heading</h2>
```

I am new to regular expression so forgive me if it is a silly question.

At the moment I have this, but realize it does not alter the captured data.

Search Criteria:

```
<h2\s*>([^<]*)</h2>
```

Replace text:

```
<h2 id="$1">$1</h2>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't really *need* regex for this, but you can do it.

Normal JavaScript example

```js
window.onload = function() {
   var element = document.getElementById("somenode");
   var text = element.innerHTML;
   element.innerHTML = text.replace(" ", "-");
};
```

```html
<h1 id="somenode">Hello world!</h1>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using the Dreamweaver search and replace function (creating a macro) so I need the regular expression, unless of course there is a way to do it in this way.

Comment: Also your example relies on the element having an id, when in fact I need to create the id from the text node. Sorry if I was unclear on this.

Comment: oh, you're trying to do a find and replace to set the ID in dreamweaver, not a dynamic javascript thing?

Comment: yes, so want to know whether it is possible to alter the $1 variable with a similar .replace(" ", "-") function.

Answer (score 0):

I have had to use a work around for now by doing what I wanted in stages.

This is what I have done so far.

To change

```
<h2>1. Something Here</h2>
```

to

```
<h2 id="Something-here">1. Something Here</h2>
```

To find all heading tags excluding h1...

```
        dw.setUpFindReplace({searchString: '<h([^1])>([^<]*)', 
    replaceString: '<h$1 id="$2">$2', searchSource: true, 
matchCase: false, ignoreWhitespace: false, 
useRegularExpressions: true, searchWhat: 'document'});
                dw.replaceAll();
```

to remove any numbers at the beginning of the id...

```
        dw.setUpFindReplace({searchString: '<h([^1]) id="\s*(\d+\s+|\d+,\d+\s+|\d+\.)', 
replaceString: '<h$1 id="', searchSource: true, matchCase: false, 
ignoreWhitespace: false, useRegularExpressions: true, 
searchWhat: 'document'});
            dw.replaceAll();
```

to hyphenate the id...

```
     dw.setUpFindReplace({searchString: '<h([^1]) id="(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s*', 
replaceString: '<h$1 id="$2-$3', 
    searchSource: true, matchCase: false, 
    ignoreWhitespace: false, useRegularExpressions: true, 
    searchWhat: 'document'});
                        dw.replaceAll();
```